# Why does python only read last line of a csv?

Tags: python, csv, io

This is what csv looks like

`2015-05-16,3.99
 2015-05-16,4.0`

And here is the code, which tries to convert the csv into a dict:

```
with open('log.csv') as filename:
    reader  = csv.reader(filename,delimiter=',') #fieldnames=['Date','GPA'] 
    display = {row[0]:row[1] for row in reader}
    print display
```

Output:

```
$python test.py
{'2015-05-16': 4.0}
```

This is what it should look like:

```
$ python test.py
{'2015-05-16':3.99,'2015-05-16': 4.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that: a dictionary needs to have *different keys*, and your CSV has two entries with the same key (May 16th).

If you change log.csv, your code works as expected:

```
{'2015-05-16': '3.99', '2015-05-17': '4.0'}
```

You can do something to make the keys different, such as add a line number:

```
display = { (row[0], i):row[1] for i, row in enumerate(reader) }
```

will output

```
{('2015-05-16', 0): '3.99', ('2015-05-16', 1): '4.0'}
```

Or you can use an *array* of dicts (and get a different output, but now with all the data):

```
display = [ { row[0]:row[1] } for row in reader ]

[{'2015-05-16': '3.99'}, {'2015-05-16': '4.0'}]
```

Or you can try and *group* all the values of a same key together, e.g.

```
{
    '2015-05-16': [ '3.99', '4.0' ],
    '2015-05-17': [ '3.14159' ]
}
```

But otherwise, every identical key in the dictionary will overwrite any previous occurrence, so that you'll always 'see' only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to insert different value for existing key in dict, it overrides the previous value